# Ordering of needle / haystack in Lisp functions

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

While learning Lisp, I've seen that if there are two parameters to a function, where one is a single element or a subset (needle), and the other is a list (haystack), the element or subset always comes first.

Examples:

```
(member 3 '(3 1 4 1 5))
(assoc 'jane '((jane doe)
               (john doe)))
(subsetp '(a e) '(a e i o u))
```

To me, it seems as if there was a rule in Lisp that functions should follow this guidance: Part first, entire thing second.

Is this finding actually based on a guideline in Lisp, or is it accidentally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions like `member` and `assoc` are at least from 1960.

I would simply expect that it followed mathematical notation, for example in set theory:

```
e ∈ m
```

Since Lisp uses prefix notation, the predicate/function/operator comes first, the element second and the set is third:

```
(∈ e m)
```

John McCarthy had a Ph.D. in Mathematics.

Generally it is also more useful in Common Lisp to have set-like argument last:

```
(defun find-symbol (name package) ...)
```

The actual definition in Common Lisp is:

```
(defun find-symbol (name &optional (package *package*)) ...)
```

This allows us to use the current package as a useful default.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. Are there more modern functions that do not follow this schema?

Answer (score 2):

Lets see. The first McCarthy LISP from 1960 had the list sometimes as the first argument. See [page 123 in this LISP manual](http://history.siam.org/sup/Fox_1960_LISP.pdf). E.g.

```
;; 1960 maplist
(defun maplist (list function)
  ...)
```

Now this is perhaps because this function was one of the first higher order functions that were made. In fact it predated the first implementation as it was in the first Lisp paper. In the same manual on page 125 you'll find `sassoc` and it looks very much like `assoc` today:

```
(defun sassoc (needle haystack default-function)
  ...)
```

Both of these look the same in the next [version 1.5 of the language](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/LISP/book/LISP%201.5%20Programmers%20Manual.pdf). (See page 63 for `maplist` and 60 for `sassoc`)

From here to Common Lisp there are divergent paths that joins again. A lot of new ideas came about but there has to be a reason to break compatibility to actually do it. I can think of one reason and that is support for multiple lists. In Common Lisp `maplist` is:

```
(defun  maplist (function &rest lists+)
  ...)
```

A quick search in the CLHS for common argument names in "wrong" order gave me  [`fill`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_fill.htm), [`map-into`](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/fun_map-into.html), and [`sort`](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/fun_sortcm_stable-sort.html). There might be more.

Peter Norvigs [style guide](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~nau/cmsc421/norvig-lisp-style.pdf) say to follow conventions but not more detailed than that. When reading Scheme SRFIs they often mention defacto implementations around and what Common Lisp has as solution before suggesting something similar as a standard. I do the same when choosing how to implement things.

Comment: There's a good reason for maplist, mapcar to take their function first:  an *arbitrary* number of lists follow.  For map-into, there always has to be result sequence to map into, whereas there can be lots of arguments.  That means that it would probably be either (map-into result function . arglists) or (map-into function result . arglists).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I mentioned that perhaps is why they (MacLisp perhaps) broke compatibility with LISP 1.5. I quoted "wrong" since I'm sure there are reasons for the order :-)

Comment: Yes, I see that you mentioned why the functions that would have multiple arguments would put them last, but I was commenting that for map-into and fill, the same reasoning means that these aren't really "wrong".\